Не удается подключиться к базе данных PSQL(posrgresql) на python/
возникла проблема при попытке подключиться к БД СУБД PSQL. перепробовал много гайдов с ютуба, везде выдает две ошибки следующего характера: 1)имя хоста не определено
2) имя пользователя не определено
пробовал много разных вариантов с разных источников и везде одна и та же песня.
(см скрины)



import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host = localhost,
    database = new,
    user = ganzzaz,
    password = 12345
    )

если кто сталкивался с подобной проблемой, пожалуйста, распишите, как вы решили и каким кодом конектились к базе данных.
спасибо, всем удачи

Ну кавычки же нужно ставить. Сейчас все эти штуки воспринимаются как переменные питона, которые интерпретатор не находит. Видимо правильно так:
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect(
    host = "localhost",
    database = "new",
    user = "ganzzaz",
    password = "12345"
    )

Кавычки можно двойные как у меня, можно одиночные, питону без разницы. Я поставил двойные, потому что они более явные на вид.
Можно все эти параметры брать и из переменных питона, но эти переменные нужно заранее определить тогда.

хахахаха. спасибо огромное!!! совсем забыл!!! все сработало!!
